# Column Mapping in R

Tags: r, mapping

I have two columns.One column says 'Degree' consists of 27000 rows of character from Data frame A .like

```
master's degree
master of business administration - mba
master of business administration (mba)
b.art.des
master of engineering (m.eng.)
master of engineering studies
master of business administration (mba)
bachelorâ€™s degree
pgdip
```

Now I have 3 separate CSV file (name as UG_alias, PG_alias, phd_alias) which contains aliases for undergraduate, postgraduate, and doctorate, like for undergraduate UG_alias contains following entry in it

```
bachelor
bsc
b sc
btech
b tech
b engg
bbm
bfa
bs
llb
bds
b eng
bdes
```

for postgraduate PG_alias contains

```
master
post graduation
msc
m sc
mba
m tech
```

and for doctorate phd_alias contains

```
doctor
phd
ph d
dphil
```

Now I want to map Degree column of Data frame A with all these 3 aliases which are present in 3 different files and produce output like this

```
pg
pg
pg
ug
pg
pg
pg
ug
pg
```

For UG I am trying following code.

```
A$Degree[A$Degree %like% UG_Alias$Degree] <- "pg"
```

But not able to achieve the desired output.Please help me find out some solution.

Comment: Do you want to identify rows for which the `Degree_Alias` does not match the `Degree`?

Comment: yes and if those aliases match then to replace them with some keyword like pg for master, ug for bachelor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to expand on this if you have a good sense of which abbreviations are used and which education levels are mentioned.

```
# create regular expressions
master <- "[Mm]aster|M\\.?([Ss][Cc]?|E(ng)?|A)"
bachelor <- "[Bb]achelor|BSc"

# conditional assignment using pattern matching
A$Degree[grepl(master, A$Degree) & grepl(master, B$Degree_Alias)] <- "pg"
A$Degree[grepl(bachelor, A$Degree) & grepl(bachelor, B$Degree_Alias)] <- "ug"
```

Comment: Actually, I have 19 alias of postgraduate and similarly 17 for undergraduate and 12 for doctorate.And I using separate CSV file of these alias.How I can achieve using separate CSV files of these alias.

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a [good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to play around with.

Comment: Not appropriate to ask posters to contact you in person - please post sufficient detail in your question to allow others to assist you, Don't ask for one-to-one help - that is not fair nor supportable under Stack Overflow rules.